# Extract street right of way width from ROW polygon using street centerline

Tags: polygon, line, measurements

In the image below, I want to extract the width of each street's ROW, which would be twice the distance of each streets centerline to the nearest parcel boundary.

Its slightly difficult to see, but I have a sample measurement drawn on Division ST of about 60ft.

Eventually, I want to have a field in the street centerline called row_width which would be this measurement of 60ft, etc. Any shortcuts to handling this short of measuring each street's actual row?

[image: Screenshot of line distance]

Answer (score 1):

In the idea world you have a good idea. In the real world the ROW is a legal description based on parcels of where to road is placed. The centerline is the center of the roadway no matter where the road is in the right of way. I've worked for a county doing parcels and the roads for a 911 system. The road only has to be somewhere within the right of way and often is not centered in it. It's common for people to take the centerline and buffer it to get the road as a ROW polygon but this messes with the parcel sizes.

I would expect to see the distance from the start of a segment on the left/right side different then at  the end of the road segment. Making this a tough problem to program against.

Comment: I've seen the argument come up a lot when working with tax parcel data...sounds good, but in reality, not so much. And I think I'm realizing now after reading your comment, how ineffective this would be in the long run...we get our data from the county, and they're continuously updating the row data, so it would be difficult to keep that in sync. Regardless, I appreciate the comment.